# How to make a picture blend in into background

Tags: graphics

Let's say I have a background based on this CSS:
background: linear-gradient(180deg, #005AFA 0%, #6400AF 100%);
Then I need to place an image over that background. Is there a way to make the image blending into the background? The background is much bigger than the picture. The picture is a company logo. This is a more theoretical question. I am looking for some fundamental knowledge since I am not a graphic designer.

Thanks for help.

Comment: [background-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode)?

Comment: This is not  a Browser environment. I showed css just to explain what kind of background I am working with. I was thinking more like make a picture truly transparent but again I am not a graphic designer, I might be doing it in a wrong way,  Is making a picture transparent actually going to work?

Comment: To me, it is unclear what you are asking. Yes, you can blend two images together. Many APIs/languages support this OOB or you can write your own code. If you just want to see what it will look like, download GIMP and play around with the blending modes.